# How do I modify nginx.conf when utilizing Docker?

Tags: docker, visual-studio, nginx, azure-devops

I have inherited a `Microsoft Visual Studio` MVC project for modification and I now need to allow users to upload files to the web server.  I utilize `Windows 11` and `IIS Express` from within `MS Visual Studio` for development purposes and there is no issue with `IIS.`  However, the app runs in production on a `Ubuntu-based` server running `NGINX` as a web server.

PROBLEM: When I attempt to upload a file larger than 1MB from my browser to the production server I receive the error message "413 Request Entity Too Large." After scouring the web I have discovered: (a) `NGINX` invokes the 1MB limit by default; and (b) it is necessary to modify the `nginx.conf` file by adding the `NGINX` "client-max-body-size" directive.

I have located the `nginx.conf` file on the production server and have browsed it with `Nano.`  However, I have stopped short of attempting to modify and save the file due to the presence of `Docker.`  Admittedly, I know virtually nothing of `Docker` and, unfortunately, the principals who set up this server have long since departed the Company.  Furthermore, it is unclear to me whether simply modifying the `nginx.conf` file and restarting `NGINX` on the production server will do the trick given what I presume to be  the necessity to involve `Docker.`

As an aside, my customer utilizes `Azure DevOps` to facilitate collaboration.  I regularly stage changes to my project using `Git` from within `MS Visual Studio` and subsequently use a `Ubuntu` `update_app.sh` script to push the changes into production.  I had previously attempted to modify the `nginx.conf` file included with the local copy of my MVC project.  The file was pushed via `Azure DevOps` to the production server but the modified `nginx.conf` file would not push to production, presumably due to the presence of `Docker.`

I would appreciate someone providing me with an explanation of the interaction between `Docker` and `NGINX.`  I would further appreciate any tip on how to get the modified `nginx.conf` file pushed into production.

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: The solution depends on your ops setup which is very hard to get a feel for from your post. There's no documentation on how your deployment process works? Editing a file on a production server might be how it's done, but seems very error prone.

Comment: Thanks for your very prompt reply.  I agree, making changes directly to a production server seems very risky.

Comment: @Hans  The ops setup is as follows. (1) Code changes are made in MS Visual Studio. (2) Code changes are pushed via Azure DevOps to a GitHub repo for staging. (3) A script is run on the production server to apply changes to the Docker container.  Script contents: (a) docker network create nginx-network; (b) docker-compose down; (c) git pull git@ssh.dev.azure.com:v3/{repo}; (d) docker-compose build --force-rm; (e) docker-compose up -d.  I am looking for a solution to modify nginx.conf and the Docker files locally (in VS) then use the 3-step DevOps/Git process to upload them.

Comment: Is the nginx.conf part of a repo? And is the nginx container built using Azure DevOps? That would be a good way to do it. Then you'd change the nginx config in your repo and a DevOps pipeline would build a new image and deploy it to production.

Comment: @Hans Yes, I have a local copy of nginx.conf and Dockerfile in the repo on my dev machine.  I have verified the contents of my dev machine to be a mirror image of both the GitHub repo and the prod server.  Modifying the nginx.conf file is simple.  However, I have no clue what I'm doing with Docker, hence my apprehension.

Comment: Additional information.  I receive the following error message in ssh when attempting to push the modified nginx.conf file from Visual Studio to Azure DevOps / Git to the Ubuntu production server:  "Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge: nginx.conf. Aborting."

Answer (score 0):

Thankfully this is pretty straightforward and NGIX has good documentation on this topic (see [Copying Content and Configuration Files from the Docker Host](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/installing-nginx/installing-nginx-docker/#maintaining-content-and-configuration-files-on-the-docker-host) section of [Deploying NGINX and NGINX Plus on Docker](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/installing-nginx/installing-nginx-docker/#maintaining-content-and-configuration-files-on-the-docker-host)).

1. Find the `Dockerfile` for the deployed solution (typically in project or solution root directory)
2. Copy the contents of the current NGIX configuration file (either from browsing the container image or finding configuration files within source)
3. Create a directory named `conf` within your source.
4. Copy the current configuration into the a file within `conf` and apply any changes to the configuration file.
5. Update `Dockerfile` to copy files within `conf` into the container where NGIX loads configuration files upon startup. Add the following line into `Dockerfile` after the line `FROM ngix` (note: line may vary but should be obvious its using `ngix` as base image): `COPY conf {INSERT RELATIVE PATH TO CONF PARENT FOLDER}`

This will copy your local configuration file into the container upon creation which NGIX will load upon startup.

**Note**: There are other solutions that support configuration changes without rebuilding the container.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am going to continue searching for a method which will allow me to modify nginx.conf and Dockerfile locally (within my Visual Studio solution) then push them for staging using Azure DevOps and Git.  I've discovered the following script which is run on the production server to push the changes from GitHub to the Docker container. Script contents: (a) docker network create nginx-network; (b) docker-compose down; (c) git pull git@ssh.dev.azure.com:v3/{repo}; (d) docker-compose build --force-rm; (e) docker-compose up -d.  This would seem to be more straight-forward.

Comment: Sure, that would work. Shutdown container, update config via SSH, then start the container.

Comment: I received the following error message in SSH when attempting to push the modified nginx.conf file from Visual Studio to the production server via the Azure DevOps/Git pipeline: "Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge: nginx.conf."  I'm not sure what the error message is telling me.